# QTreeView no show when placed inside QDockWidget

Tags: c++, qtreeview, qdockwidget

I want to show a file system using QTreeView on a QDockWidget. The tree will be dynamically changed, so I decided to use QTreeView instead of QTreeWidget.

Here is my code:

```
QFile file(":/default.txt");
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
TreeModel model(file.readAll());
file.close();

QTreeView w;
w.setModel(&model);
swatch1->setWidget(&w);
w.setEnabled(true);

addDockWidget(leftarea, swatch1);
```

swatch1 is of type QDockWidget. The above code is inside a function body of type (inherited from) MainWindow. The code runs smoothly, and the tree does not show up.

I also tried another way: putting QTreeView into a QVBoxLayout (using setWidget method), which in turn be put into a QDockWidget (using setLayout method). This 2nd code also runs smoothly, and the tree does not show up.

This code is copied from a working example on Qt Creator IDE, and I tested it working. The only difference is, in the original QTreeView example, the above code is placed inside the main() { ..... } function.

Does anyone has a working example, putting QTreeView into QDockWidget and working (the code actually shows the tree)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: if the only difference is your code in not inside the main function, are you sure it actually gets executed at all? and does the tree view contain data

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what went wrong in the OP. However, I made a minimal complete sample to see whether there are pitfalls:

```
// standard C++ header:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// Qt header:
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDockWidget>
#include <QFileSystemModel>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTreeView>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  cout << QT_VERSION_STR << endl;
  // main application
#undef qApp // undef macro qApp out of the way
  QApplication qApp(argc, argv);
  // setup GUI
  QMainWindow qWin;
  QDockWidget qDock;
  qDock.setAllowedAreas(Qt::AllDockWidgetAreas);
  QTreeView qTreeView;
  QFileSystemModel qFSModel;
  qTreeView.setModel(&qFSModel);
  QString path = QDir::currentPath();
  QModelIndex indexPath = qFSModel.index(path);
  qTreeView.scrollTo(indexPath);
  qDock.setWidget(&qTreeView);
  qWin.addDockWidget(Qt::TopDockWidgetArea, &qDock);
  qWin.show();
  // run application
  return qApp.exec();
}
```

Compiled and tested it with VS2013, Qt 5.6 on Windows 10 (64 bit):

[image: Snapshot of testQDockTreeView]

As can be seen in the snapshot, the `QTreeView` is visible (docked and undocked). I checked that both re-act on mouse clicks - they did.

(I guess this is one of my most minimal Qt applications I ever wrote.)

Answer (score 0):

Scheff,

Thank you very much for your answer. Sorry I may not be clear about what I am asking: the tree become visible when this code section is in the main() { ....} function:

```
QFile file(":/default.txt");
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
TreeModel model(file.readAll());
file.close();

QTreeView w;
w.setModel(&model);
w.show();
```

But the same code (almost same) does not working (program runs but the tree is not visible) when this section of code is in a class function inside MainWindow and QTreeView is added to a QDockWidget:

```
QFile file(":/default.txt");
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
TreeModel model(file.readAll());
file.close();

QTreeView w;
w.setModel(&model);

swatch1->setWidget(&w);
addDockWidget(leftarea, swatch1);
```

here, leftarea is a Qt:DockWidgetArea, and swatch1 is an object of type inherited from QDockWidget. when run this program, swatch (a QDockWidget) is visible, but not the tree. still struggling ...

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved. The original code I wrote by itself is correct, but it is in an object method, and as soon as the execution leaves the object, the tree is destroyed.

So, it is a C++ variable scoping problem, not exactly a Qt problem. I have been using python for a while, and just switch back to C++.

Scheff, thank you for your posting confirmed to me that the Qt code is correct, and suggests to me that something else is wrong.